# How to convert working with date time in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have datetime field like `2017-01-15T02:41:38.466Z` and would like to convert it to `%Y-%m-%d` format. How can this be achieved in pandas or python?

I tried this

`frame['datetime_ordered'] = pd.datetime(frame['datetime_ordered'], format='%Y-%m-%d')`

but getting the error

`cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @NitinVarghese. Please refer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: try `pd.to_datetime(frame['datetime_ordered'], format='%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: The following worked  d_parser= lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0,parse_dates=['datetime_ordered'],date_parser=d_parser)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

Comment: I suggest that you add it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked

```
d_parser= lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
for filename in all_files: 
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0,parse_dates['datetime_ordered'],date_parser=d_parser) 
    li.append(df) 
    frame =pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
date_str="2017-01-15T02:41:38.466Z"
a_date=pd.to_datetime(date_str)
print("date time value", a_date)
#datetime to string with format
print(a_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```